# How to have a timer running in background to perform an operation after certain periods?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a button which has a limit of 5 per day and 30 per month. Every time it is clicked it is reduced by 1 from the daily remaining and monthly remaining. Once it has been clicked 5 times, the remaining clicks per day are 0 and he monthly remaining is 25. How do I reset this counter every 24 hours back to 5 in the background, even whilst the app is not running or the device is not turned on. And how do I do the same for after 30 days (month). Currently, I am using SharedPreferences to update the values when I want to. But I want this to happen periodically not every time the app is launched

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("dailyRemaining", dailyRemaining).apply(); //5
sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("monthlyRemaining", monthlyRemaining).apply(); //30
```

Comment: [Unifying Background Task Scheduling on Android](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/11/unifying-background-task-scheduling-on.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relatively simple task to do in the background when it can simply be done when the app launches. Implementing and maintaining background tasks in itself is a great deal of work, so if you don't need to do anything in the Background upon a date changing (like sending a notification, or sending that info to a backend, etc.), I would suggest keep it simple and at the UI level.
You could do something like this in your main `Activity` or override your `Application` class an do it in there):

```
// Build today date and current month strings which will be used as keys
String todayDate = getDateFromFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String currentMonth = getDateFromFormat("MM-yyyy");

// Try to get the remaining limit from sharedpreferences, and give them default
// values if they don't exist yet
int remainingForToday = sharedPreferences.getInt(todayDate, 5);
int remainingThisMonth = sharedPreferences.getInt(currentMonth, 30);

// When the user clicks on the button, decrement and save the remaining 
sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(todayDate, remainingForToday - 1).apply();
sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(currentMonth, remainingThisMonth - 1).apply();

// Utility function to get the date time strings using native Java classes
private String getDateFromFormat(String format) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return formatter.format(today.getTime());
}
```

What the above is doing is making a `key` out of todays date, and the current month which would be unique for each day, and each month. Simply check your remaining limits based on that.

Comment: If the user changes his local date and time, this would effect how everything works?

Comment: Also how do I convert this to Java, sorry kinda new

Comment: Also the DateTimeFormatters requires a minimum SDK version of 26 > which is a problem for me

Comment: First, regardless of what implementation you choose, if you are storing things only locally on the device and not verifying the date through a backend online, yes, the user will be able to change the device date start using the button again. You will need some way to verify the date online to check if it is valid or been changed. If you don't have a backend, I'm sure there are other ways to check it online.It is a very common problem and likely to have been solved.

Comment: Second, see my updated answer for Java code. And third, my previous code was just to give the concept of getting dates as keys using a library that I usually use in my projects for dates. I have added a code snippet which uses `SimpleDateFormat` which has been there since the beginning. Have a little search with `SimpleDateFormat` online to see different ways it can be used in if my provided code doesn't work as it is only stub code which I have written from memory, hopefully it'll work right out the box. Hope it helps.

Comment: The formatting code, does not work. I changed it to return formatter.format(today.getTime()); which works

Answer (score 3):

For perform any task after certain periods, you have to refer the android work manager or android job.

Work manager [ https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager ]

Evernote android job [ https://github.com/evernote/android-job ]

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reset values every 24 hours you can use `AlarmManager`. With it you can schedule execution of service that will reset values in `SharedPreferences`. But the `AlarmManager` has it problems, once phone is reboot you have to reschedule it. Don't worry [here is the guide](https://medium.com/@valeriachub/classic-chain-alarmmanager-service-broadcastreceiver-with-new-features-from-android-m-and-n-14fc0b4cf0db) that explains how to handle all these things.

Also you can use new [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) API. + hand [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#5) how to use it